# How can I ask for multiple name inputs and place them all in the poll? (Telegram bot)

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

here is my code right now

"my first time dealing with telegram bots its for a hackathon"

```
bot.onText(/\/dare/, async msg => {
    const namePrompt = await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Who would you like to dare", {
        reply_markup: {
            force_reply: true,
        },
        
    });
   
    bot.onReplyToMessage(msg.chat.id, namePrompt.message_id, async (nameMsg) => {
        const name = nameMsg.text;
        await bot.sendPoll(msg.chat.id,"who would you like to dare!",[name, 'aaurush', 'shine', 'yenlik', 'zuzana']);
    });
    
});
```

so I want to replace the Aarush shine yenlik etc with user input.